# Using Contract.ForAll in Code Contracts

Tags: c#, static-analysis, code-contracts, forall

Okay, I have yet another Code Contracts question.  I have a contract on an interface method that looks like this (other methods omitted for clarity):

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IUnboundTagGroup))]
public abstract class ContractForIUnboundTagGroup : IUnboundTagGroup
{
    public IUnboundTagGroup[] GetAllGroups()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IUnboundTagGroup[]>() != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.ForAll(Contract.Result<IUnboundTagGroup[]>(), g => g != null));

        return null;
    }
}
```

I have code consuming the interface that looks like this:

```
    public void AddRequested(IUnboundTagGroup group)
    {
            foreach (IUnboundTagGroup subGroup in group.GetAllGroups())
            {
                AddRequested(subGroup);
            }
            //Other stuff omitted
    }
```

`AddRequested` requires a non-null input parameter (it implements an interface which has a Requires contract) and so I get a 'requires unproven: group != null' error on the subGroup being passed into `AddRequested`.  Am I using the ForAll syntax correctly?  If so and the solver simply isn't understanding, is there another way to help the solver recognize the contract or do I simply need to use an Assume whenever GetAllGroups() is called?

Comment: The latest version has enabled `ForAll`, you might want to give it a try :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Code Contracts User Manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) states, "The static contract checker does not yet deal with quantiers ForAll or Exists." Until it does, it seems to me the options are:

1. Ignore the warning.
2. Add `Contract.Assume(subGroup != null)` before the call to `AddRequested()`.
3. Add a check before the call to `AddRequested()`. Maybe `if (subGroup
   == null) throw new InvalidOperationException()` or `if (subGroup != null)
   AddRequested(subGroup)`.

Option 1 doesn't really help. Option 2 is risky because it will circumvent the `AddRequested()` Requires contract even if `IUnboundTagGroup.GetAllGroups()` no longer ensures that post-condition. I'd go with option 3.

Comment: Thanks; I'm thinking I'll probably go with using Assume, since the original code (pre-Contracts) did not have a null check.  It also cleanly marks the various places where the static prover needed 'help' so that hopefully I can go back and remove some of them as the prover becomes more powerful.