# Code contracts, forall and custom enumerable

Tags: c#, code-contracts, enumerable, forall

I am using C# 4.0 and Code Contracts and I have my own custom `GameRoomCollection : IEnumerable<GameRoom>`.

I want to ensure, that no instances of `GameRoomCollection` will ever contain a `null` value element. I don't seem to be able to this, though. Instead of making a general rule, I have tried to do a plain and simple example. The `AllGameRooms` is an instance of `GameRoomCollection`.

```
private void SetupListeners(GameRoom newGameRoom) {
  Contract.Requires(newGameRoom != null);
  //...
}
private void SetupListeners(Model model) {
    Contract.Requires(model != null);
    Contract.Requires(model.AllGameRooms != null);
    Contract.Assume(Contract.ForAll(model.AllGameRooms, g => g != null));
    foreach (GameRoom gameRoom in model.AllGameRooms)
        SetupListeners(gameRoom);//<= Warning: Code Contracts: Requires unproven: newGameRoom != null 
}
```

Can anyone see, why I haven't proven, that `gameRoom` is not `null`?

**EDIT:**

Adding a reference for the object before iterating does not work either:

```
IEnumerable<IGameRoom> gameRooms = model.AllGameRooms;
Contract.Assume(Contract.ForAll(gameRooms, g => g != null));
foreach (IGameRoom gameRoom in gameRooms)
    SetupListeners(gameRoom);//<= Warning: Code Contracts: Requires unproven: newGameRoom != null
```

**EDIT2:**

However: If I convert the game room collection type to an array, it works fine:

```
IGameRoom[] gameRoomArray = model.AllGameRooms.ToArray();
Contract.Assume(Contract.ForAll(gameRoomArray, g => g != null));
foreach (IGameRoom gameRoom in gameRoomArray)
    SetupListeners(gameRoom);//<= NO WARNING
```

Is this caused by the fact, that you cannot define a rule for methods of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface?

**EDIT3:** Can the problem somehow be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104856/using-contract-forall-in-code-contracts)?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue when using `List` or `IList`, rather than an array. I was trying to use it as an Invariant, and dozens of warnings are popping up...

Answer (score 2):

I think this might have to do with purity of the GetEnumerator method. [PureAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute.aspx)

Contracts only accept methods that are defined as [Pure] (side effect free).

Some extra information [Code Contracts, look for purity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx)

Qoute:

> Purity
>
> All methods that are called within a
>   contract must be pure; that is, they
>   must not update any preexisting state.
>   A pure method is allowed to modify
>   objects that have been created after
>   entry into the pure method.
>
> Code contract tools currently assume
>   that the following code elements are
>   pure:
>
> Methods that are marked with the
>   PureAttribute.
>
> Types that are marked with the
>   PureAttribute (the attribute applies
>   to all the type's methods).
>
> Property get accessors.
>
> Operators (static methods whose names
>   start with "op", and that have one or
>   two parameters and a non-void return
>   type).
>
> Any method whose fully qualified name
>   begins with
>   "System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract",
>   "System.String", "System.IO.Path", or
>   "System.Type".
>
> Any invoked delegate, provided that
>   the delegate type itself is attributed
>   with the PureAttribute. The delegate
>   types System.Predicate and
>   System.Comparison are considered
>   pure.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because `model.AllGameRooms` returns an `IEnumerable<GameRoom>` which could be different on each property access.

Try using:

```
var gameRooms = mode.AllGameRooms;
Contract.Assume(Contract.ForAll(gameRooms, g => g != null));
foreach (IGameRoom gameRoom in gameRooms)
    SetupListeners(gameRoom);
```

Comment: What is the type of the property `AllGameRooms`? Is it strongly typed to `IEnumerable<GameRoom>` or is it something else?

Comment: It is my custom GameRoomCollection type which inherits from IEnumerable<GameRoom>.

Comment: Maybe a bit picky - but you can't inherit IEnumerable<GameRoom>, it's an interface - you can only implement it.